# update text field by only modifying a specific expression

Tags: mysql

Is that possible to update a text field in a table by searching a specific expression and changing only this expression,I mean update by searching expression then removing this one and concatenate the new one to the rest of the text?

**Example**

```
this is a HTML text....<img src="path/to/my/image/empty_gif.gif" />.......html
```

how can I grep the img expression to give the new image path?
This is how I can concatenate a new text

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET FIELD = CONCAT('expression ',FIELD) WHERE CONDITION;
```

but how to remove the previous one?

Comment: Are you talking about the REPLACE function? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: if you mean use regex to match the path then replace it, try [mysql-udf-regexp](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function get_between_tags($tag1, $tag2, $string) {
    $outdata='';
    if (eregi("$tag1(.*)$tag2", $string, $out)) {
        $outdata = $out[1];
    }
    return $outdata;
}
$res = mysql_query("SELECT FIELD FROM TABLE WHERE CONDITION", $mysql_conn);
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
        $result=get_between_tags("Start of the text I want to find","End",$row['FIELD']);
        mysql_query("UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD= replace(FIELD,'".$result."','new text') WHERE CONDITION");
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried to search the wanted expression framed betwwen to expressions and then use the replace function to replace the found expression(old expression)by the new expression.